# How to convert strings to numeric values?

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, nlp

I am cleaning a csv file on jupyter to do machine learning.
However, several columns have string values, like the column "description":

[image]

I know I need to use NLP to clean, but could not find how to do it on jupyter.
Could you advice me how to convert these values to numeric values?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Numerical values are better for creating learning models than words or images.*(Why? dimensionality reduction)*

Common machine learning algorithms expect a numerical input.

> The technique used to convert a word to a corresponding numerical value is called word embedding.

In [word embedding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word_embedding), strings are converted to [feature vectors](https://www.researchgate.net/post/in_simple_words_what_do_you_mean_by_feature_vector_in_image_processing)(numbers).

Bag of words, [word2vec](https://code.google.com/archive/p/word2vec/), [GloVe](https://nlp.stanford.edu/projects/glove/) can be used for implementing this.

It is generally advisable to ignore those fields which wouldn't be significant for the model.So include description only if is absolutely essential.

Comment: Thank you so much. I decided to drop description column for now. I will study these links you sent here later on.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are describing is that of converting categorical data, usually in the form of strings or numerical ID's to purely numerical data. I'm sure you are aware that using numerical ID's has a problem: it leads to the false interpretation that the data has some sort of order. Like `apple < orange < lime`, when this is not the case.

It is common to use [one-hot encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-hot) to produce numerical indicator variables. After encoding one column, you have N columns, where N is the amount of unique labels. The columns have a value of 1 when the corresponding categorical variable had that value and 0 otherwise. This is especially handy if there are few unique labels in one column. Both `Pandas` and `sklearn` have these sorts of functions available, albeit they are not as feature complete as one would hope.

The "description" column you have seems to be a bit trickier, because it actually includes language, not just categorical data. So that column would need to be parsed or handled in some other way. Although, the one-hot encoding scheme may very well be used for all the words in the description, producing a vector that has more 1's.

For example:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(['a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'a', pd.np.nan])
>>> pd.get_dummies(df)
   0_a  0_b  0_c
0    1    0    0
1    0    1    0
2    0    0    1
3    1    0    0
4    1    0    0
5    0    0    0
```

Additional processing would be needed to get the encoding word by word. This approach considers only the full values as variables.

Comment: Thank you! I will try one-hot encoding

Comment: So first I need to get all the value(word) of the "description" column and after that I  will be needed to do one-hot encoding?

Comment: @Trey I would very carefully try to figure out what is the correct level of resolution you want the encoding to be in. But that could involve taking individual words. The data ultimately decides. If you do it word by word, then yes, every word will have the encoding and by combining all words' encodings you get the final vector.